# Cannot resolve symbol "parent" in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-2.3

I created a new project in Android Studio 2.3.2 and getting this error `String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' with value 'parent').`
Similarly for `toLeftOf`,`toRightOf` and `toTopOf`.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vgDY.png)

Comment: Are you adding the dependency to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2` in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Try rebuilding your project Build->Rebuild Project. That sometimes clear up these reference issues.

Comment: changing `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4` to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2` solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the dependency to

```
com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
```

in `build.gradle`